# Trouble with parsing and "doing math" with numbers (A simple java calculator)

Tags: java

I am attempting to take a simple String statement and parse it to print out a simple answer.

So far, I cannot figure out why I am consistently getting wrong answers.

Say for example - I plug in a String with "2 * 3 * 4 * 5 / 2 / 3 / 2".

The expected answer is 10, but I receive the answer of 1.5

Can anyone see the issue here? I assume it is not a case of order of operations (I have not got that far yet).

```java
public class TestingforExcel {
    static String tableholder = "2 * 3 * 4 * 5 / 2 / 3 / 2";
    public static void main(String args[]){
        String[] fracEquationHolder = tableholder.split(" ",tableholder.length()); // holds the fractions and operator
        String operators = "";
        double operand;
        double operand2;
        double answer = 0;

        for(int i =0; i <= (fracEquationHolder.length-2); i+=2){
            operators = fracEquationHolder[i+1];
            operand = Double.parseDouble(fracEquationHolder[i]);
            operand2 = Double.parseDouble(fracEquationHolder[i+2]);
            if(operators.indexOf("+")>=0){
                answer = operand + operand2;
            }else if(operators.indexOf("-")>=0){
                answer = operand - operand2;
            }else if(operators.indexOf("*")>=0){
                answer = operand * operand2;
            }else if(operators.indexOf("/")>=0){
                answer = operand / operand2;
            }else
                System.out.print(answer+""); 
        }
        System.out.print(answer+""); 

    }
```

Comment: And the variable names, I know they are wonky. This project is for a much bigger project I am putting together for school.

Comment: On the final run through your loop, you evaluate `3 / 2`.  What were you expecting the answer to be?  You need to use `answer` in place of `operand` on every iteration except for the first one.

Comment: oh darn... You are quite right!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class TestingforExcel {
    static String tableholder = "2 * 3 * 4 * 5 / 2 / 3 / 2";
    public static void main(String args[]){
         String[] fracEquationHolder = tableholder.split(" ",tableholder.length()); // holds the fractions and operator
        String operators = "";
        double operand;
        double operand2;
        double answer = Double.parseDouble(fracEquationHolder[0]);

        for(int i =0; i <= (fracEquationHolder.length-2); i+=2){
            operators = fracEquationHolder[i+1];
            operand = Double.parseDouble(fracEquationHolder[i]);
            operand2 = Double.parseDouble(fracEquationHolder[i+2]);
            if(operators.indexOf("+")>=0){
                answer += operand2;
            }else if(operators.indexOf("-")>=0){
                answer -= operand2;
            }else if(operators.indexOf("*")>=0){
                answer *=  operand2;
            }else if(operators.indexOf("/")>=0){
                answer /=   operand2;
            }else
                System.out.print(answer+""); 
        }
        System.out.print(answer+""); 

    }
```

You have to problems:

1- you get 1.5 because this is the last operation (3/2)
    The you should use (answer += operand + operand2)

2- you should use the sum of the last operation not the operands

Comment: Glad to hear that.

Answer (score 0):

You are always caculating using `operand` and `operand2`. But if there are some previous value in `answer` then you should calculate `answer` with `operand2`. Use following

```
if(answer > 0)
    operand = answer;
else 
    operand = Double.parseDouble(fracEquationHolder[i]);
```

Also I only pointed out the problem of your code not the logic. your code doesn't follow BODMAS rule. so implement that part

Answer (score 0):

In the first iteration you have to read 2 operands. From the 2nd operator use the answer from previous operation as operand1.